# Use of instances( ) in gnm R package

Tags: r, gnm

I'm trying to fit a generalized Lee-Carter model with the R package gnm.
I built a data frame

```
EXPO <- read.table("dati/Exposures.txt",header=TRUE,skip=0)
DEATH <- read.table("dati/Deaths.txt",header=TRUE,skip=2) 
base=data.frame(
D=DEATH$Total,
E=EXPO$Total,
X=as.factor(EXPO$Age),
T=as.factor(EXPO$Year))
```

Now, while this works

```
LC1 <- gnm(D/E~ as.factor(X)+Mult(as.factor(X),as.factor(T)),
                 weights=E,family=binomial(link="logit"),data=base)
```

when I move to this one I get an error

```
LC2 <- gnm(D/E~ as.factor(X)+instances(Mult(as.factor(X),as.factor(T)),2),
                 weights=E,family=binomial(link="logit"),data=base).
```

Specifically,

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'D/E' not found
```

I already tried to replace "D/E" with "base$D/base$E" in the formula, but it didn't work...

Comment: If you compute `DE = D/E` beforehand, does that work? `gnm`'s `instances` might not appropriately handle complex responses.

Answer (score 1):

I am the maintainer of `gnm`. This appears to be a bug in `instances` which I will make a note to fix. In the meantime you can specify the instances in long form:

```
LC2 <- gnm(D/E ~ as.factor(X) + Mult(as.factor(X), as.factor(T), inst = 1) + 
           Mult(as.factor(X), as.factor(T), inst = 2),
           weights = E, family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = base)
```

Alternatively pre-computing the proportions as suggested by Josh will also work.

Comment: Thank you. I pre-computed the proportion in a new variable and it worked fine!